# i want to set tap gesture on every image that can be moved, but gesture is not set on every image

Tags: ios

i want to add UIImageView on click of button add, and want to set tap gesture on every image that can be moved, somehow i added image but gesture is not set on every image

## for add image

```
 -(IBAction)addImageAction:(id)sender{

if (flag == true) {
    imgNew = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];
    flag = false;
}else{
    imgNew = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imgNew.frame.origin.x+15, imgNew.frame.origin.y+15, 70, 70)];
}

[imgViewArray addObject:imgNew];
[viewMain addSubview:imgNew];
[imgNew setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[imgNew setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Doraemon.png"]];
[self gestureMethod];
}
```

## touch method

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if ([touch view] == img1)
{
    NSLog(@"its 1st image");
    // set imageview to 1st image
     img = img1;
}else if ([touch view] == img2){
    NSLog(@"its second image");
     // set imageview to 2nd image
     img = img2;
}else {
    img = imgNew;
}
[self gestureMethod];
NSLog(@"%@",touch.view.description);

}
```

in gestureMethod i done code for moving image and zoom in and zoom out

Comment: actually tap gesture is working in any single event , not a multiple u need multiple  allocate the separate gesture for each image , in my choice in this place allocate the button and get the index simple'

Comment: Not getting your question? What you want actually with the tap event?